# Does this word fall under the accepted "rules" of constructing English words?

Tags: etymology, linguistics

I have a bilingual friend that will occasionally use the word "presentful" (meaning more or less "presented well"). Obviously, this isn't in the dictionary, but in context it's perfectly understandable. (Even out of context, you can basically figure out what it means). It was occurring to me: even if it's technically *not* in the dictionary, this actually seems like a linguistically valid way to construct the word (especially since there are other "dictionary words" - e.g. "restful" - that appear to be constructed in similar ways). Am I correct about that? Is there some kind of "rule" about what constitutes a "validly" constructed word?

Comment: If the word enters general use, it will eventually be included in dictionaries. Words are added to dictionaries regularly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it claims a candidate word to be a word without any evidence. Wordness is ultimately usage-driven, and claiming that D-I-Y letter assemblages not in a recognised dictionary are actually words undermines the credibility of a site aiming to avoid mediocrity.

Comment: The question of whether 'presentful' can be produced via -ful suffixation is an interesting question about the processes that underlie the morphosyntax of English. If here's not the right place, maybe the Linguistics site could be (depending on how the question is phrased)? As I'm new to this site, can questions only be asked about words that appear in the dictionary?

Comment: It might be helpful to see if there's a parallel.  "Rest" is a noun, "present" in the meaning of giving a presentation is not a noun.  Since the word your friend coined doesn't follow the pattern, it's a bit of a stretch for me.  (However, that doesn't prevent the two of you from having a special word that you both understand.)

Comment: Phonologically, there's a parallel - 'resentful' - but I agree that morphosyntactically 'presentful' doesn't pattern like other words with -ful suffixation

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Undermines the credibility of the site" seems like an overreacton at best. It's actually fairly routine to construct words by attaching a suffix to an existing word, so this seems like a perfectly valid question about the correct use of English to me.

Comment: It's fairly routine to judge wordness by checking in a reasonable dictionary. ELU is not here to endorse non-standard usages and abusages. The whole question of inventing new 'words' to personal specifications has been addressed here on more than one occasion. English Language and Usage, not English Futures. And not JS's take on English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Using that standard, at what point did "tintinnabulation" (invented by Edgar Allen Poe) become a "real word?"

Comment: The point is that it _is_ one now, and thus not off-topic on ELU. There has to be a measure of control, or the whole thing becomes a free-for-all. There is no central body to govern just how productive ways of producing derived words can be. Inclusion in a respected dictionary is the best arbiter of wordness we have (there will be a study on frequency of use).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are a lot of dialect words of English that may not be recognised as English because they are not part of the standard variety, and as such they won't appear in a dictionary. This is also true with syntactic constructions - non-standard syntactic constructions won't necessarily appear in an English grammar book. However the ELU guideline page says that questions are welcome on dialect differences. Does this not include questions asking whether a construction or a word is found in non-standard varieties, or questions about innovations in general?

Comment: 'Dialect differences' demand that there are areas where the usage is common. Not a nonce usage by someone's bilingual friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, 'presentful' does 'fall under the accepted “rules” of constructing English words'. Specifically, the word is formulated via suffixation, a common process of English word formulation. Suffixation of '-ful' in particular is, if not common, at least commonly intelligible. *OED* returns 1300 words and phrases ending with that suffix.

The long answer is more interesting. 'Presentful', with the meaning you've given, would be an unlikely formulation. Typically, words ending with the suffix '-ful' are formed from nouns. Words ending with '-ful' formed from verbs are not unknown; 'forgetful' is a prominent example, as is the example you gave, 'resentful'. Examples of words formed from verbs with the suffix '-ful' added are comparatively rare. but other examples do exist.

As I mentioned in a comment, the meaning you've given for 'presentful' would not be easy for me to reach out of context, and whether I would understand it in context would depend entirely on the particular context, as well as how the word was pronounced. To be consistent with the meaning you intend, the pronunciation would emphasize the second syllable. So also the second syllables of 'forgetful' and 'resentful' are emphasized).

When I pronounce 'presentful' with emphasis on the second syllable, I notice that the 'p' at the beginning is barely pronounced at all. The result of that loss (comparative) of the 'p' leaves a pronunciation that sounds to me very close to 'resentful'. That source of potential confusion alone would discourage me if I were to contemplate adopting the word.

It is tempting for me to sidestep or disregard the final question in the body of your post, that is, this question:

> Is there some kind of "rule" about what constitutes a "validly" constructed word?

The short answer is, again, no. The long answer is that, as "I and the schoolchildren know" (a phrase borrowed from a poem by W. H. Auden), it might be nice if there was such a rule.

In this context, though, I should mention that (a) your 'scare quotes' around 'rule' and 'validly' muddle the question, and (b) 'validly' should here be distinguished from 'soundly', in that while the formulation of 'presentful' (again, with the meaning you intend) is *valid*, I would, for the reasons given in the foregoing, not consider the formulation *sound*.